# vue-router url paths are giving a 404 in production with nodejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I am attempting to deploy a multipage vue3 frontend to an application. It works fine in development mode, but in production, when I attempt to navigate to a url via the search bar -- e.g. https://mywebsite.com/customers, I get a 404.

I am able to fix this by redirecting to the homepage using the suggestion on [vue-router's documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-mode), but then it just goes to the homepage rather than showing the actual page I would like to visit.  Is there some way around this that I am missing? An additional step or does this suggest I am misconfiguring this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by setting up the server. You need to understand what server you have installed. Go to config update and restart the server.

[Here are the Server Configurations](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)

**Apache**

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
  Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

**nginx**

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I struggled to get it working in native node.js, but express with node worked -- esp. https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-do-i-implement-connect-history-api-fallback-so-that-url-paths-redirect-to-index-html/10938/2